# Where can I unlock all the O-Powers in Pokemon Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

There's O-Powers in 6th gen Pokemon games, which are basically buffs to stats, capture rate, hatching rate etc and can be used on yourself or your friends/acquaintances/passersby.

I know you can unlock more than what you start out with, because I unlocked one early in the game (I believe it was capture rate), so **where do I find the rest of the o-powers?** (specifically hatching rate)

Comment: I assume hatching rate is probably the last one to unlock. I got one (Speed I think...) from the wierd guy in Mauville's Pokemon Center. Haven't found any others yet

Comment: I'm not sure if the one I got was Capture rate or Speed (I got both, but only remember unlocking one), I haven't found any others either. I wonder if there are none others to unlock...

Comment: Serebii strikes again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Serebii: The 'Strange Man', *Giddy*, (or at least his location in Mauville City Pokemon Center) is the source of most of the O-Powers:

> Talk to [Giddy] and he will give you an O-Power, and then another. He'll then leave and be replaced by *Hipster*. He will give you three different O-Powers before he then leaves.
>
> After that, *Bard* appears and will ask you to listen to songs, and give you two O-Powers.
>
> A new man, *Trader*, then appears and offers to trade you Secret Base Decorations for a variety of simple items such as Potions and Poké Balls. In doing so, he too will give you an O-Power.
>
> Finally, after he goes, another man, *Storyteller*, appears and tells you stories about yourself and gives you an O-Power.
>   - [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/opower.shtml)

At this point you should have all but one of the O-Powers. the last is only available after the Elite Four.

Speak to *Storyteller* again after beating the Elite Four and he will invite you up to his apartment in Mauville Hills. When there: (spoilers)

> they will tell you that they are longing for someone to give power to, and learn of a powerless man across the hall. Speak to him and he will go to their apartment. Soon, the five men explain that they want to retire and they soon start to merge with the man and the man becomes Mr. Bonding.

Just before he leaves he gives you the final O-Power.

[Source](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/opower.shtml)

Comment: Ah, this explains why I never found any more - I don't talk twice to any NPCs, heh.