# What would be the ideal 3 Pokémon games to complete a (living) Pokédex?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

There are two things I absolutely want to be able to do in the Pokémon games (I currently own the old gameboy games (blue, yellow, silver), and newer 3DS games (Alpha Sapphire and Y)), and that is to have a living Pokédex and have a Shiny team of my favourites (Blastoise, Arcanine, Tyranitar, Alakazam, Snorlax, and to be decided), and have a living Pokédex (at least one of every Pokémon type in my boxes).

The friend safari (which has an increased chance of providing shinies) is very useful to achieve the first goal, but trying to achieve the second goal, I was wondering which 3 games combined would be the ideal combination to get a complete Pokédex. Especially when it comes to legendaries.

From the fourth gen and up, preferably.

Comment: I remember reading that if you owned X&Y and Omega Ruby & Alpha Sapphire you can catch every Pokemon in the Pokédex. However, that's four games and not three. P.S. Congrats on going for a complete living Pokédex, I am going for that myself by working my way up from every game (starting with gen 3) in order!

Comment: Honestly for 95% of the Pokemon you can just wonder trade and breed/evolve for evolutions so Omega Ruby or Alpha Sapphire would be a good starting point. You only really need extra games if you don't wanna navigate the minefield that is trading on GTS for legendaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to complete the entire pokédex is using only gen 6 games. If you want to catch everything yourself, you will need all four games (due to version exclusives), but if you don't mind trading, that's the easiest way to do it.

Not only are these the only games where the Global Trade System still works, but certain features such as [restaurants](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lumiose_City_restaurants#Restaurant_Le_Wow) in XY and [blissey bases](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236550/what-is-an-easy-experience-farm-in-pok%C3%A9mon-omega-ruby-and-alpha-sapphire/236553#236553) in ORAS make it incredibly easy to level things up to evolve them. Super Training also gives you an infinite supply of evolution stones, and the active community makes it easy to find people to help you with trade evolutions.

On top of this, gen 6 also increased the rate at which you find shinies, so if you want a certain shiny pokemon, it'll be easier to get one in these games.

Source: I have a complete living dex that I originally made in gen 4, and these improvements made it *very* easy to bring it up to date in gen 6.